# Convert shapefile to PNG using GeoTools

Tags: shapefile, geotools, png

I need to know how to export a .shp file to .png in Java using geotools.

I found an example here:
[Convert geojson to png](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245875/convert-geojson-to-png).
But I need convert shapefile to PNG.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To export any type of [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) feature type to an image the [process is the same](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245875/convert-geojson-to-png?noredirect=1&lq=1) - you read in the features (or coverage) using a `DataStore`, you then render these features using a `Style` (often read from an SLD file) and then save the Java Image to a file using `ImageIO`.

So in your specific case you will need a `ShapefileDatastore` but there is no need to know that just use `DataStoreFinder` to look for a `DataStoreFactory` that can handle your requirements.

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(ShapefileDataStoreFactory.URLP.key, URLs.fileToUrl(new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.shp")));
DataStore ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
SimpleFeatureCollection fc = ds.getFeatureSource(ds.getTypeNames()[0]).getFeatures();
```

Now to render it:

```
MapContent mapContent = new MapContent();
mapContent.setTitle("Quickstart");
Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(features.getSchema());
Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(features, style);
mapContent.addLayer(layer);
```

Then we need to call the `Renderer` on that mapContent to draw it to the `Image`:

```
File outputFile = new File("states.png");
try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    ImageOutputStream outputImageFile = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fileOutputStream);) {

  int w = 1000;
  ReferencedEnvelope bounds = fc.getBounds();
  int h = (int) (w * (bounds.getHeight() / bounds.getWidth()));
  BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

  mapContent.getViewport().setMatchingAspectRatio(true);

  mapContent.getViewport().setScreenArea(new Rectangle(Math.round(w), Math.round(h)));
  mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(bounds);

  g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

  Rectangle outputArea = new Rectangle(w, h);

  GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
  LabelCacheImpl labelCache = new LabelCacheImpl();
  Map<Object, Object> hints = renderer.getRendererHints();
  if (hints == null) {
    hints = new HashMap<>();
  }
  hints.put(StreamingRenderer.LABEL_CACHE_KEY, labelCache);
  renderer.setRendererHints(hints);
  renderer.setMapContent(mapContent);
  renderer.paint(g2d, outputArea, bounds);
  ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", outputImageFile);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Running this will produce an image like this:

[image]

If you want more colour you need to produce a `Style` object either by reading in an existing SLD file or by using `StyleBuilder` both of which are [covered in the user manual](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/style.html).

Comment: sorry for not having much idea about this but it generates the .png file fine but does not allow me to open it. Any solution for this? - Im using version 23.2 of geotools

Comment: what are you using to try and open it?