# Free API/SDK for exporting map with scale and legend

Tags: export, java, software-recommendations, api, sdk

I am looking for some free/opensource GIS api/sdk (preferably in Java) to accomplish following workflow.

I have couple of raster files like tif,  and vector files like shapefiles with associated SLD styles. I have to create map from these files and export it to image map (png) with graphic scale and legend. Preferably also with north arrow and title.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoTools](https://geotools.org) is the obvious (to me) choice here. This [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/373857/79) should get you going with the vector - adding a raster is covered in the [image tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html).

Adding a title and north arrow are just standard Java graphics rendering operations.

There is a lot of code to draw "map decorations" in the [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) code base see https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/main/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/decoration and legends at https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/main/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic

Comment: Thank you. I think that GeoTools would do do job. I just coudn't find a sample with graphic scale and legend, could you please point me to some?