# How to get the the GPS coordinates corresponding to Cartesian pixel coordinates when drawing a PNG image from a GeoJSON file

Tags: python, geojson, georeferencing, java, geotools

I'm going to explain my problem. I've a classic GeoJSON file:

```
 {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "920260000A0490",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              2.2334715,
              48.8976688
            ],
            [
              2.2335159,
              48.8976081
            ],...
```

that I convert to a PNG image using [geotools.org](https://geotools.org) through @ian-turton's Java code snippet [Convert geojson to png](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245875/convert-geojson-to-png?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Here is a sub image from the resulting PNG

[image]

What I'm looking for is a way to get for a point (x, y) (some of the red points for example or any other point in the image) the GPS (lat, long) coordinates when painting the image.

The goal is, at the end of the rendering, having a list of
[[x1, y1, lat1, long1], [x2, y2, lat2, long2], ...] where

- **xi, yi** are cartesian coordinates in the image
- **lati, longi** = their corresponding GPS coordinates

Example `[[222, 500, 2.2334715, 48.8976688, ], [341, 756, 2.2335159, 48.8976081]...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on where you get your key points from but here I'm using the centroids (you can substitute your own points):

```
  AffineTransform worldToScreen = mapContent.getViewport().getWorldToScreen();
  try (SimpleFeatureIterator it = (SimpleFeatureIterator) features.features()) {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      SimpleFeature feature = it.next();
      Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();

      Point p = geom.getCentroid();
      Point2D p2d = new Point2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY());
      Point2D pOut = new Point2D.Double();
      worldToScreen.transform(p2d, pOut);
      System.out.println(feature.getAttribute("name") + " " + p2d + " -> " + pOut);
    }
  }
```

This produces the following output, which should be easy enough to write into your JSON output (though I'm not sure if mixing the coordinates in one array is legal):

```
Minnesota Point2D.Double[-94.17743611908642, 46.360073163397246] -> Point2D.Double[740.2716724869573, 238.33848517978026]
Montana Point2D.Double[-109.65900423944824, 47.04846199440962] -> Point2D.Double[592.6638962095401, 231.77509678333575]
New Mexico Point2D.Double[-106.08613015755957, 34.41655926898082] -> Point2D.Double[626.7291791347998, 352.21296567084573]
Oregon Point2D.Double[-120.53933428078462, 43.94483230888741] -> Point2D.Double[488.92625735538854, 261.36640644310984]
Utah Point2D.Double[-111.66920084078133, 39.32876391317445] -> Point2D.Double[573.4978370677052, 305.3779423378168]
Wyoming Point2D.Double[-107.55436942193711, 43.02707584077606] -> Point2D.Double[612.7303689901789, 270.11668227879613]
Arkansas Point2D.Double[-92.44486422557522, 34.92180789235074] -> Point2D.Double[756.7907409982139, 347.3957129750563]
Iowa Point2D.Double[-93.50644416139835, 42.083886007513556] -> Point2D.Double[746.6691917824414, 279.1094505056941]
Kansas Point2D.Double[-98.38015579205894, 38.482929863984666] -> Point2D.Double[700.2011770163518, 313.44247960755365]
Missouri Point2D.Double[-92.47936410598834, 38.37951692755193] -> Point2D.Double[756.4618046404737, 314.42846200071165]
Nebraska Point2D.Double[-99.81532791999376, 41.52510949882417] -> Point2D.Double[686.5176428463755, 284.43706055413736]
Oklahoma Point2D.Double[-97.5041982257254, 35.58149601643106] -> Point2D.Double[708.5529245573399, 341.1059691793974]
North Dakota Point2D.Double[-100.48470034126993, 47.46271462229255] -> Point2D.Double[680.1355648916201, 227.82543814775778]
South Dakota Point2D.Double[-100.22852335515658, 44.44637732594061] -> Point2D.Double[682.5780639304551, 256.5844654863102]
Louisiana Point2D.Double[-91.95720553784504, 31.04807717756422] -> Point2D.Double[761.440283855797, 384.32948946731807]
Texas Point2D.Double[-99.3286756609654, 31.45550825618542] -> Point2D.Double[691.157589989784, 380.44487034902045]
Connecticut Point2D.Double[-72.73828042123064, 41.605829685584546] -> Point2D.Double[944.6815922846587, 283.6674403725276]
Massachusetts Point2D.Double[-71.73571885214085, 42.237666769998924] -> Point2D.Double[954.2404355907129, 277.6432400928835]
New Hampshire Point2D.Double[-71.56273394862767, 43.69169024392468] -> Point2D.Double[955.889746354237, 263.7799692683302]
Rhode Island Point2D.Double[-71.52928731203043, 41.68199156750224] -> Point2D.Double[956.2086406428318, 282.941280984824]
Vermont Point2D.Double[-72.6622592695624, 44.0727537257665] -> Point2D.Double[945.406409891025, 260.14674989817985]
Alabama Point2D.Double[-86.82817806048864, 32.77370877345344] -> Point2D.Double[810.3425871956382, 367.8765926701101]
Florida Point2D.Double[-82.50257327248272, 28.6169278613942] -> Point2D.Double[851.5847209929722, 407.5090886893272]
Hawaii Point2D.Double[-156.2376432494753, 20.186071342476804] -> Point2D.Double[148.56357815093452, 487.8924176387127]
Georgia Point2D.Double[-83.45109299211283, 32.652468898777215] -> Point2D.Double[842.5411353896678, 369.03254458389415]
Mississippi Point2D.Double[-89.662513207191, 32.76707818749695] -> Point2D.Double[783.3188448345909, 367.9398114629898]
South Carolina Point2D.Double[-80.88367798679437, 33.901500292862934] -> Point2D.Double[867.0199489549357, 357.12375439233784]
Illinois Point2D.Double[-89.15446508894911, 40.119180002951786] -> Point2D.Double[788.162789090921, 297.841783181402]
Indiana Point2D.Double[-86.28480499934571, 39.91271166766222] -> Point2D.Double[815.5233343021844, 299.81033905422146]
Kentucky Point2D.Double[-85.27783714028817, 37.51394421613003] -> Point2D.Double[825.1241890284458, 322.6811959709457]
North Carolina Point2D.Double[-79.2520908367359, 35.53593140990896] -> Point2D.Double[882.5761864853048, 341.5404012855893]
Ohio Point2D.Double[-82.7102574363638, 40.405205884014315] -> Point2D.Double[849.6045728994336, 295.1146922347233]
Tennessee Point2D.Double[-86.32269331543374, 35.83900735963397] -> Point2D.Double[815.1620911747976, 338.65074781933384]
Virginia Point2D.Double[-78.80954049157502, 37.50686182214862] -> Point2D.Double[886.7956474489578, 322.74872249139815]
Idaho Point2D.Double[-114.65496537502375, 44.39400647311054] -> Point2D.Double[545.0303032906938, 257.0837912049906]
Wisconsin Point2D.Double[-89.7299056031134, 44.65096401051708] -> Point2D.Double[782.6762974115667, 254.6338500621153]
West Virginia Point2D.Double[-80.61012007056091, 38.64494571019326] -> Point2D.Double[869.6281650855224, 311.89775244589737]
Delaware Point2D.Double[-75.499522406912, 38.99158990422706] -> Point2D.Double[918.3547508367175, 308.59270102972266]
District of Columbia Point2D.Double[-77.01745388120375, 38.89554364226426] -> Point2D.Double[903.882154280622, 309.5084464527875]
Maryland Point2D.Double[-76.769980523672, 39.03327302676682] -> Point2D.Double[906.241669267035, 308.195276622934]
New Jersey Point2D.Double[-74.6705434188825, 40.205711649001415] -> Point2D.Double[926.2585848703515, 297.0167541047795]
New York Point2D.Double[-75.66005918947685, 42.96358741351968] -> Point2D.Double[916.8241256893875, 270.7220076239941]
Pennsylvania Point2D.Double[-77.84707536254771, 40.89864663287908] -> Point2D.Double[895.9721944457331, 290.410020776488]
Maine Point2D.Double[-69.21754146982204, 45.337449436537] -> Point2D.Double[978.2497969671805, 248.08860952873658]
Michigan Point2D.Double[-85.72971514472697, 44.86521547692555] -> Point2D.Double[820.8157942414758, 252.59108654650373]
Washington Point2D.Double[-120.39836844165161, 47.37975260712036] -> Point2D.Double[490.2702849037437, 228.61643286352916]
Alaska Point2D.Double[-152.82595656620205, 64.37552888232169] -> Point2D.Double[181.09203268202964, 66.57155972232431]
Arizona Point2D.Double[-111.6594634633185, 34.29559508311375] -> Point2D.Double[573.5906773163731, 353.3662890516706]
California Point2D.Double[-119.64054396147455, 37.25514453351573] -> Point2D.Double[497.4957019582605, 325.1487009003562]
Colorado Point2D.Double[-105.54544030956286, 39.00007627137654] -> Point2D.Double[631.8843433596434, 308.51178843909423]
Nevada Point2D.Double[-116.65016518455421, 39.3480519389064] -> Point2D.Double[526.0072298640057, 305.19404219508317]
```

If you want to go in the opposite direction (from pixels to world coordinates) then you can use the `screenToWorld` transform:

```
  AffineTransform screenToWorld = mapContent.getViewport().getScreenToWorld();
  for (int i = 100; i < bufferedImage.getHeight(); i += 100) {
    for (int j = 100; j < bufferedImage.getWidth(); j += 100) {
      Point2D p = new Point2D.Float(j, i);
      Point2D out = new Point2D.Float();
      screenToWorld.transform(p, out);
      System.out.println(p + " -> " + out);
    }
  }
```

Which gives this:

```
Point2D.Float[100.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-161.33115, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[200.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-150.84283, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[300.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-140.3545, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[400.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-129.8662, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[500.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-119.377884, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[600.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-108.88957, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[700.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-98.40125, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[800.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-87.91294, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[900.0, 100.0] -> Point2D.Float[-77.42463, 60.86945]
Point2D.Float[100.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-161.33115, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[200.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-150.84283, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[300.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-140.3545, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[400.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-129.8662, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[500.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-119.377884, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[600.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-108.88957, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[700.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-98.40125, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[800.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-87.91294, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[900.0, 200.0] -> Point2D.Float[-77.42463, 50.381134]
Point2D.Float[100.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-161.33115, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[200.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-150.84283, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[300.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-140.3545, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[400.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-129.8662, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[500.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-119.377884, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[600.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-108.88957, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[700.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-98.40125, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[800.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-87.91294, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[900.0, 300.0] -> Point2D.Float[-77.42463, 39.89282]
Point2D.Float[100.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-161.33115, 29.404505]
Point2D.Float[200.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-150.84283, 29.404505]
Point2D.Float[300.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-140.3545, 29.404505]
Point2D.Float[400.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-129.8662, 29.404505]
Point2D.Float[500.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-119.377884, 29.404505]
Point2D.Float[600.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-108.88957, 29.404505]
Point2D.Float[700.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-98.40125, 29.404505]
Point2D.Float[800.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-87.91294, 29.404505]
Point2D.Float[900.0, 400.0] -> Point2D.Float[-77.42463, 29.404505]
```

Comment: That works! thanks. However, this gives the reversed order. I can get the x, y of a given lat, long. But I'm looking for the lat, long of a given x, y in image. How to do the reverse transformation: `Point2D.Double[ 2521.658307496138, 1278.7240069843829] -> Point2D.Double[3.3726695744779076, 48.3047587391181]`

Comment: My bad, sorry I see that I badly asked my question. I'm editing it.